# EF4.1 Many-to-Many Relationship : DisplayInInbox for each user

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, entity-relationship

For some reason I cannot get my head around this one... I have a Private Messaging system which allows users to send eachother PM's. The user can also delete a message from his/her inbox, but when that happens, it shouldn't be deleted from the other user's inbox. For that, I believe I should have a many to many relationship between the User and Message entities. But, how should I map this relationship to allow users to delete the messages from their inbox (which I thought I'd create a boolean for: DisplayInInbox) and not delete it from the other user's inbox as well?

My current model which does not work is as follows:

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(3000)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastViewed { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public bool DisplayInInbox { get; set; } 
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

and on the user class I have this property:

```
    public virtual ICollection<Message> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
```

Do I need two booleans or would one be enough? And how should I map this relationship eventually?

**UPDATE:**

Ok so now here's my model:

```
public class Inbox
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Message")]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastViewed { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }

    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual User Receiver { get; set; } 
}

public class Message 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(3000)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Inbox> ReceivedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Inbox> SentBy { get; set; }
}
```

And on the User class:

```
    public virtual ICollection<Inbox> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any boolean. The meaning of boolean is what you actually model by many-to-many relationship. You will have message in database only once and inbox presence will be defined by many-to-many relation.

The problem is that you want to keep some additional information related to message and user. Because of that you must expose junction table as separate entity:

```
// The message
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(3000)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentMessage")]       
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Sender")]
    public int SenderId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Message ParentMessage { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Inbox> ReceivedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }
}

public class Inbox
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Message")]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastViewed { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; } 

    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Inbox> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> SendMessages { get; set; }
}
```

Now removing the message from user's inbox simply means removing the record from `ReceivedMessages` but it will not delete the message - it will only delete record in `Inbox` table.

Edit:

I updated the code sample to support all your additional requirements. Now:

- Each `Message` can have multiple receivers
- Receiving `Message` is done by separate entity called `Inbox` which will allow you deleting message per `User` and using properties like `IsRead` per `User`.
- `Message` has optional `ParentId` and `ParentMessage` so you can track reactions / responses to other messages.
- `Message` has `Sender` and `SenderId` and in the same time `User` have collection of sent messages. In my opinion a `Message` is sent by a single `User` so this relation has nothing to do with an `Inbox` and must be directly between `Message` and `User`.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for! Now I need to do major refactoring to my PM system... Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I think one thing that is still missing... I need to know who sent the message and who received it. Your code only shows who received it, right?

Comment: and one more thing... this is supposed to be more of a conversation-like PM system... that is "Google Mail" style where when you reply to an email, it shows up right below it in the same conversation. And that is why I'm using the "ParentId" field... I'm assuming that when ParentId is null, it means this message is a reply and not a new thread...

Comment: @Kassem: All these can be solved. Add `Sender` as relation to `Message` and use `ParentId` to build message hierarchy.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I've updated my post. I guess that should be it, right?

Comment: mmm I am not sure about this model... The Message is actually the same, the difference is who's sending it and who's receiving it. So in order to map this correctly, there should be a ReceivedMessages and SentMessages collections on the User class? Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: One more thing if you do not mind... Do I need some Fluent API code to make the relationships more explicit? Like how would it know how to do the mapping between the Inbox and the User entities?

Comment: @Kassem: I modified the sample to model all your requirements.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I used a slightly different model (before your reply). Yours seems a little better but I was so relieved after I got everything to work. Now the only thing that's not working is the "Delete" which caused the re-factoring in the first place :) I should delete the `Inbox`, right? It does complain about "multiplicity" - probably a cascading delete issue...

Comment: @Kassem: I'm not oracle :) I have to see the code and real exception you get to be able to think about the problem.